# InetAddress.getHostAddress() ipv6 compliant?

Tags: java, ipv6

Is  [InetAddress.getHostAddress()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostAddress%28%29) ipv6 compliant in JDK 1.6?

Specifically I am doing

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()
```

Is it ipv6 compliant? Does it work for both ipv4 and v6 addresses?

Comment: The conclusion was it is indeed ipv6 compliant.

Comment: Can you please approve my edit - then I will accept the answer. As it stands now, people aren't sure whether answer is yes or no.

Comment: I can't. The community have rejected it and they had valid reason to reject it.

Comment: Note that question is not about Inet6Address but about the interface InetAddress.

Comment: `Inet6Address` is of `InetAddress`. `InetAddress` is a factory pattern that returns the IPvX implementations. Your statement makes no sense as `InetAddress` uses `Inet6Address`. As for the valid reason, your edit didn't couldn't be justified as the answer provided is sufficient to answer your question. Additional edit couldn't be justified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at the code of InetAddress class and it is indeed doing the right thing.

```
  if (isIPv6Supported()) { 
      o = InetAddress.loadImpl("Inet6AddressImpl"); 
  } 
  else { 
      o = InetAddress.loadImpl("Inet4AddressImpl"); } 
      return (InetAddressImpl)o; 
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

The extended class [`java.net.Inet6Address`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Inet6Address.html) is IPv6 compliant.

JavaDoc:

> This class represents an Internet Protocol version 6 (IPv6) address.
>   Defined by RFC 2373: IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture.

Basically, if you do `InetAddress.getByName()` or `InetAddress.getByAddress()` the methods identify whether the name or address is an IPv4 or IPv6 name/address and return an extended `Inet4Address`/`Inet6Address` respectively.

As for `InetAddress.getHostAddress()`, it returns a **null**. You will need `java.net.Inet6Address.getHostAddress()` to return an IPv6 string representable address.

Comment: Thanks - is InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() safe then? please look at my edit as well.

Comment: @Fakrudeen, I guess you have to do `if (InetAddress.getLocalHost() instanceof Inet6Address)` to see if it returns an `Inet6Address` or read the `InetAddress` source code.

Comment: @Elite, I looked at the source code. It seems to be doing the right thing depending whether IPv6 is supported. But I just wanted to confirm with the community.  InetAddress static block:    
 if (isIPv6Supported()) {
     o = InetAddress.loadImpl("Inet6AddressImpl");
 } else {
     o = InetAddress.loadImpl("Inet4AddressImpl");
 }
 return (InetAddressImpl)o;
    }

Comment: @Fakrudeen, There you go! :-) Well done in doing your research.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code to test based on the above analysis:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    InetAddress localIP;
    try {
        localIP = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
         if(localIP instanceof Inet6Address){
             System.out.println("IPV6");
         } else if (localIP instanceof Inet4Address) {
             System.out.println("IPV4");
         }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```