# IPv6 support in Java

Tags: java, ipv6

I am trying to test a java program for IPv6 support on my local system having Windows 7 OS. I have assigned an IPv6 address and have disabled IPv4 in Network Connection.

When I execute `ipconfig` command I get IPv6 address as output.

However, when I execute below java code I get `127.0.0.1` which is an IPv4 address

```
System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv6Stack","true");

InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
System.out.println(addr.getHostAddress());
```

As per my understanding the above code should print `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`.

Have I missed something?

Comment: Problem is resolved. I was setting wrong System property.

Correct property is `System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv6Addresses","true")`

Comment: Is your question the solution itself?

Comment: When I asked the question I was not aware of the solution.

Comment: @vinod please write that as an answer (possible immediately) and mark it as accepted (possible after two days)

Comment: @vinod It will be very nice if you share your solution here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Problem is resolved. I was setting wrong System property. Correct system property that needs to be set is

```
System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv6Addresses","true")
```

After setting this property the IPv6 address assigned in Network Connection will be displayed.

IPv6 loopback address can be retrieved using below code.

```
InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress().getHostAddress()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Inet6Address](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/Inet6Address.html) class.

```
java.net.Inet6Address.getHostAddress()
```

Refer this question.
[InetAddress.getHostAddress() ipv6 compliant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908398/inetaddress-gethostaddress-ipv6-compliant)